# Downloading Image each 10 seconds as service (no GUI) in Android?

Tags: java, android

- How to download an image from web server each 10 second with service on Android, without notifications, just background work ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Just not sure from where to start, and I wished 1st to check the best practices before chose an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials that will show you how to create a service using the android API. I hate to be just placing links for an answer but I don't particularly want to do take the fun out of coding it yourself.

**Creating a service**

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

**Downloading the image**

You could then create a background thread that performs a HttpGet to the location on the webserver then sleeps for 10 seconds. HttpGet is part of the Apache HttpClient API and is available since API level 1 (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html)

**Saving the image**

Where you save it depends on whether you want it to be placed on internal/external storage. The following link will help you with saving files using an output stream: -

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Everything is more than great on the articles you have posted me to read, one more thing - how to start the service after boot of the OS?

Comment: Use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) Intent and this can launch your Service.